# WP cron trouble

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to send emails notification using wp cron but my code doesn't works.

I'm using a plugin to run my wp cron job every day and the function called is named   EVENT NOTIFICATION.

In functions.php I put this code:

```
function EVENT_NOTIFICATION_function() {

  global $wpbd;
  
  $test_data = '2025-05-04';

  $results=$wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'data_concert' AND meta_value = '$test_data'" );

  foreach ($results as $row) {
  $post_id = $row->post_id;

  // Send email to;
  $email_to = 'tester1@gmail.com, tester2@gmail.com';

  // Set the email subject
  $email_subject = 'Event Alert';
  
  // Set the email content
  $content = 'Hey dude remember that you have to play!';

  // Set the email headers
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

  wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $content , $headers );
 }
}

add_action( 'EVENT_NOTIFICATION', 'EVENT_NOTIFICATION_function' );
```

There's something wrong on this part:

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'data_concert' AND meta_value = '$test_data'" );

  foreach ($results as $row) {
  $post_id = $row->post_id;
```

cause if I delete it everything works well!

I don't find how to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean this $test_data to be a string or did you mean to be a variable and to concatenate it?  If you meant to concatenate it try this:  "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'data_concert' AND meta_value = ' & $test_data

Comment: Hi Jim, I mean a line of code like that:

$results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_om_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'data_servizio' AND meta_value = '2025-05-04'");